# stop other form1 from submitting when submitting form2 using php/javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

this is the real code I am doing the first post contains the same problem,

as you can see the form 1 buttons is to control the iteration of the $_SESSION['clicks'] value i am using sessions in this form,

the form 2 buttons are to echo out the array for corresponding names that are retrieved from another array.

and the problem is every time the buttons in form2 is clicked or called out in php the other form or form1 gets submitted too

```
     <?php 
        session_start();
        $results_per_page = 10;
        if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = 1;
        }else{
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT*FROM doctors"); 
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT*FROM doctors ORDER BY doctor_name ASC");
        $stmt2->execute();

        while($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
            $result[] = [
                'name' => $row['doctor_name'],
                'degree' => $row['doctor_degree'],
                'foe' => $row['doctor_foe'],
            ];
        }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <?php
                    $next = "<button class='btn-nav' name='plus'>Next</button>";
                    $prev = "<button class='btn-nav' name='min'>Prev</button>";

                    $next_un = "<button class='btn-nav' name='plus' disabled>Next</button>";
                    $prev_un = "<button class='btn-nav' name='min' disabled>Prev</button>";
                    $results = count($result);
                    $num_of_pages = ceil($results/$results_per_page);

                    $clicks = 0;
                    if (isset($_POST['plus'])) {
                        $_SESSION['clicks'] += 10 ;
                    }else {
                        $_SESSION['clicks'] -= 10;
                    }

                    if ($_SESSION['clicks']>0) {
                        echo $prev;
                    }else{
                        echo $prev_un;
                    }
                    if ($_SESSION['clicks']>=($results-10)) {
                        echo $next_un;
                    }else{
                        echo $next;
                    }

                    $newarr = array_slice($result, $_SESSION['clicks'], 10);
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="appt">
                <?php 
                    foreach ($newarr as $row) {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']
                        ."</td><td>".$row['degree']
                        ."</td><td>".$row['foe']."</td></tr>";
                    }

                    echo $new_count = count($newarr);
                 ?>
            </table>
            <table class="appt">
                <form method="post">
                    <tr><th>Set Appointment</th></tr>
                    <?php
                        switch ($new_count) {
                            case '10':
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa6">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa7">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa8">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa9">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button type="button" name="sa10">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '9':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa6">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa7">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa8">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa9">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '8':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa6">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa7">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa8">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '7':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa6">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa7">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '6':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa6">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '5':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa5">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '4':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa4">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '3':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa3">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            case '2':
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa2">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                            default:
                                echo '<tr><td><button name="sa1">Set Appointment</button></td></tr>';
                                break;
                        }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php 
            $sa1 = $_POST['sa1'] ?? '';
            $sa2 = $_POST['sa2'] ?? '';
            $sa3 = $_POST['sa3'] ?? '';
            $sa4 = $_POST['sa4'] ?? '';
            $sa5 = $_POST['sa5'] ?? '';
            $sa6 = $_POST['sa6'] ?? '';
            $sa7 = $_POST['sa7'] ?? '';
            $sa8 = $_POST['sa8'] ?? '';
            $sa9 = $_POST['sa9'] ?? '';
            $sa10 = $_POST['sa10'] ?? '';


            if (isset($_POST['sa1'])) {
                echo $newarr[0]['name'];
                echo $newarr[0]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[0]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa2'])) {
                echo $newarr[1]['name'];
                echo $newarr[1]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[1]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa3'])) {
                echo $newarr[2]['name'];
                echo $newarr[2]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[2]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa4'])) {
                echo $newarr[3]['name'];
                echo $newarr[3]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[3]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa5'])) {
                echo $newarr[4]['name'];
                echo $newarr[4]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[4]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa6'])) {
                echo $newarr[5]['name'];
                echo $newarr[5]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[5]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa7'])) {
                echo $newarr[6]['name'];
                echo $newarr[6]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[6]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa8'])) {
                echo $newarr[7]['name'];
                echo $newarr[7]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[7]['foe'];
            }else if (isset($_POST['sa9'])) {
                echo $newarr[8]['name'];
                echo $newarr[8]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[8]['foe'];
            }elseif (isset($_POST['sa10'])) {
                echo $newarr[9]['name'];
                echo $newarr[9]['degree'];
                echo $newarr[9]['foe'];
            }
            //session_destroy();
         ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What you're saying sounds incorrect. You can have as many forms as you like in your page, but the user can only submit one at a time. Submitting one form doesn't cause the other one to be submitted. The only exception to that would be if you've specifically written some JavaScript code which causes that to happen...have you done that?

Comment: sorry i update my post, can you please read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi think I understand what you're trying to say.

just wrap the logic from your form with the following:

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST['btn1'])) {
     //Code for form 1
   }

   if(isset($_POST['btn2'])) {
     //Code for form 2
   }
```

Comment: Although you may end up being right, this is somewhat speculative. We don't know for sure how the PHP processes the forms, and whether that is causing whatever the OP is seeing (which isn't clear, since their description appears to talk about something which isn't possible). It's preferable to provide answers which rely on information from the question, not on guesswork. Get 50 rep, post a comment asking for clarification, follow the question, and then answer once you're sure what the specific issue is.

Comment: yes i am using sessions, is that affecting the performance of the other forms?

Comment: @MelvinEsguerra there was no mention of sessions previously.... And my snippet has nothing to do with sessions...
By the way are you familiar with loops (for, foreach, while)
There is no need for all those echos, you can just close the php tags write the html and reopen the php tags.
The input name can be array as well, so you won't have sa1 ... sa10...

Comment: @edluis97 Sorry if you thought I was "flexing my rep" but actually no, I was just trying to keep the quality of answers high on the site. Nothing personal :-). And I didn't say you can't help. But...answers which rely too much on guesswork / assumptions can often end up being an unhelpful distraction. At stackoverflow we prefer to answer based on the available facts as far as possible. If the facts aren't available, ask for clarification. 50 rep is 5 upvotes, so it isn't a long journey, even if you can't give much time. I don't give mountains of time here, I've just been here a while!

Answer (score 1):

sorry for bothering you guys, i found my mistake. it is the if else of the session['click'] that is triggering the events which is causing for the said form1 to be submitted. and thanks for the suggestion of making my codes more shorter!

```
            <?php 
                include 'connection.php';
                session_start();
                $results_per_page = 10;
                if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                    $page = 1;
                }else{
                    $page = $_GET['page'];
                }
                $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT*FROM doctors"); 

                $stmt1->execute();

                $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT*FROM doctors ORDER BY doctor_name ASC");
                $stmt2->execute();

                while($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
                    $result[] = [
                        'name' => $row['doctor_name'],
                        'degree' => $row['doctor_degree'],
                        'foe' => $row['doctor_foe'],
                    ];
                }
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title></title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    th, td{
                        width: 200px;
                        text-align: left;
                    }
                    div{
                        display: flex;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <form method="post">
                        <?php
                            $next = "<button class='btn-nav' name='plus'>Next</button>";
                            $prev = "<button class='btn-nav' name='min'>Prev</button>";

                            $next_un = "<button class='btn-nav' name='plus' disabled>Next</button>";
                            $prev_un = "<button class='btn-nav' name='min' disabled>Prev</button>";
                            $results = count($result);
                            $num_of_pages = ceil($results/$results_per_page);

                            $clicks = 0;
                            if (isset($_POST['plus'])) {
                                $_SESSION['clicks'] += 10 ;
                            }else if (isset($_POST['min'])){
                                $_SESSION['clicks'] -= 10;
                            }

                            if ($_SESSION['clicks']>0) {
                                echo $prev;
                            }else{
                                echo $prev_un;
                            }
                            if ($_SESSION['clicks']>=($results-10)) {
                                echo $next_un;
                            }else{
                                echo $next;
                            }

                            $newarr = array_slice($result, $_SESSION['clicks'], 10);
                        ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table class="appt">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Doctor's Name</th>
                            <th>Educational Background</th>
                            <th>Field of Expertise</th>
                            <th>Set An Appointment</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            foreach ($newarr as $row) {
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']
                                ."</td><td>".$row['degree']
                                ."</td><td>".$row['foe']."</td></tr>";
                            }

                            echo $new_count = count($newarr);
                         ?>
                    </table>
                    <table class="appt">
                        <form method="post">
                            <tr><th>Set Appointment</th></tr>
                            <?php for ($i=1; $i < ($new_count+1); $i++): ?>
                                <?php echo '<tr><td><button id="submit" name="sa'.$i.'">Click me!</button></td></tr>'; ?>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                        </form>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    $sa1 = $_POST['sa1'] ?? '';
                    $sa2 = $_POST['sa2'] ?? '';
                    $sa3 = $_POST['sa3'] ?? '';
                    $sa4 = $_POST['sa4'] ?? '';
                    $sa5 = $_POST['sa5'] ?? '';
                    $sa6 = $_POST['sa6'] ?? '';
                    $sa7 = $_POST['sa7'] ?? '';
                    $sa8 = $_POST['sa8'] ?? '';
                    $sa9 = $_POST['sa9'] ?? '';
                    $sa10 = $_POST['sa10'] ?? '';


                    if (isset($_POST['sa1'])) {
                        echo $newarr[0]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[0]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[0]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa2'])) {
                        echo $newarr[1]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[1]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[1]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa3'])) {
                        echo $newarr[2]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[2]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[2]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa4'])) {
                        echo $newarr[3]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[3]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[3]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa5'])) {
                        echo $newarr[4]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[4]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[4]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa6'])) {
                        echo $newarr[5]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[5]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[5]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa7'])) {
                        echo $newarr[6]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[6]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[6]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa8'])) {
                        echo $newarr[7]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[7]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[7]['foe'];
                    }else if (isset($_POST['sa9'])) {
                        echo $newarr[8]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[8]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[8]['foe'];
                    }elseif (isset($_POST['sa10'])) {
                        echo $newarr[9]['name'];
                        echo $newarr[9]['degree'];
                        echo $newarr[9]['foe'];
                    }
                 ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You're welcome, @Melvin. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.
I wish you great luck in this long (really long) road. Keep practicing it and try not to be too overwhelmed. One step at a time goes a long way.

Comment: thankyou very much! i will keep that in mind